# Create a new column only with the year from a string variable

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column in the dataset that contains only the year. The `dpro` columns contains more text example: 1913/12/30 : classé MH. I´ve tried with other arguments but Something is missing and I am junior in python. Thanks

Code:

```
monuments["year_protec"] = pd.to_datetime(monuments["dpro"], format ="%Y",errors ="coerce")
monuments.head()
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your `dpro` column?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For help with non-working code, you need to make a [mre] including example input, expected output, and actual output -- or if you get an error, the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) for specifics. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Hello Jon, example,  dpro: 1913/12/30 : classé MH, 1932/12/29 : classé MH, 1948/04/13 : inscrit MH...but a few rows have corrupted data (like references to the year 20115) so I used in the function errors="coerce".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to clean up the string first, and convert it into `datetime` format and finally get the year part.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

s = ["1913/12/30 : classé MH", "1913/12/30 : classé MH","1913/12/30 : classé MH"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date" : s})

#df 

    date
0   1913/12/30 : classé MH
1   1913/12/30 : classé MH
2   1913/12/30 : classé MH
```

```
drop = re.compile(r'[^(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})]')
df["clean_date"] = df["date"].str.replace(drop, "")
df["year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["clean_date"], format = "%Y/%m/%d").dt.year
# df
    date                    clean_date  year
0   1913/12/30 : classé MH  1913/12/30  1913
1   1913/12/30 : classé MH  1913/12/30  1913
2   1913/12/30 : classé MH  1913/12/30  1913
```

Looks into `re.compile`, `\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}` is used to compile a regular expression pattern, which tells python to find the string where match a rule with :

> \d{4} : digit appears four times.

> \/ : a slash.

> \d{2} : digit appears two times.

And we can see that `\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}` construct a `date-like` string, for example, `2022/04/10`.

Moreover, the `^` before the given pattern `\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}` means that I want to exclude the pattern.

So, what I did later is that I replace the string with the part **is not a date-like** pattern with empty string.

Which means :

We can separate `1913/12/30 : classé MH` into two parts:

1. `1913/12/30`: date-like part.
2. `: classé MH` : not a date-like part.

```
df["date"].str.replace(drop, "")
```

The code will choose the `not a date-like part` and replace it with `""`.

For more information about regular expression, please check https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html .

Comment: Thanks a lot Denny. Fantastic your answer. Please explain the first line of the code o some documentation

Comment: @adrimon07 Answer updated.